# Use varwidth with algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e, varwidth

I’m trying to draw a box around an `algortihm2e` construct, like this:
[image: A box as i want it.]

I tried to use the `varwidth` package to get a box with the natural width of the content:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}
    \fbox{\begin{varwidth}{10cm}
        \If{condition}{
            loop content
        }
    \end{varwidth}}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunatly, the result looks like this:
[image: The box i get.]
It looks like `varwidth` takes the maximum width when an `\If` or `\For` construct is used inside. How can I get a box with the natural width?

Comment: The concept of natural width does not apply.  Like \vbox, it will fill the available space (\hsize}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meanwhile, I came up with a hack myself: Overwriting the internal macro of `algorithm2e` that draws the blocks and use the `varwidth` environment there.

Here is a solution for the `vlined` option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\algocf@Vline}[1]{%     no vskip in between boxes but a strut to separate them, 
    \strut\par\nointerlineskip% then interblock space stay the same whatever is inside it
    \algocf@push{\skiprule}%        move to the right before the vertical rule
    \vbox{\hbox{\vrule%
        \begin{varwidth}{\hsize}%
            \vbox{\algocf@push{\skiptext}%move the right after the rule
                \hbox{%
                    \algocf@addskiptotal%
                    \begin{varwidth}{\hsize}%
                        #1% inside the block
                    \end{varwidth}%
                }%
                \Hlne}%
        \end{varwidth}%
    }\vskip\skiphlne}%
    \algocf@pop{\skiprule}%\algocf@subskiptotal% restore indentation
    \nointerlineskip}% no vskip after

\renewcommand{\algocf@Vsline}[1]{%    no vskip in between boxes but a strut to separate them, 
    \strut\par\nointerlineskip% then interblock space stay the same whatever is inside it
    \algocf@bblockcode%
    \algocf@push{\skiprule}%        move to the right before the vertical rule
    \hbox{\vrule%               the vertical rule
        \begin{varwidth}{\hsize}%
            \vbox{\algocf@push{\skiptext}%move the right after the rule
                \hbox{\algocf@addskiptotal%
                    \begin{varwidth}{\hsize}%
                        #1% inside the block
                    \end{varwidth}%
                }}%
        \end{varwidth}%
    }%
    \algocf@pop{\skiprule}% restore indentation
    \algocf@eblockcode%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \fbox{\begin{varwidth}{\hsize}
            \If{condition}{
                loop content

                a line longer than the loop header
            }
    \end{varwidth}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Resulting box around if statement]

With other options for the block style `\algocf@Noline` might have to be adapted similarly (not tested).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a kludge using `\tikzmark`s to locate the top, bottom and right side (more or less).

Note that without the minipage, algorithm2e will use space outside the margins.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
      \tikzmark{A}\If{condition\tikzmark{B}}{
            loop content
        }\tikzmark{C}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
      %\draw[red] (pic cs:A) -- (pic cs:B) -- (pic cs:C);
      \path (pic cs:B) node[right, inner sep=0pt] (BB) {\phantom{ \textbf{then}}};
      \path (pic cs:C) ++(0,\baselineskip) coordinate (CC);
      \draw (pic cs:A) ++(0, \ht\strutbox)  rectangle (BB.east |- CC);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Your solution requires `\tikzmark{B}` to be placed at the end of the longest line, when the loop body is wider than the loop header. I’m interested in a more general solution that works independent of what is inside the loop body.