# Algorithm in box and settings

Tags: algorithm2e

I'd like to restrict my algorithm in a box that it adapts at the lenght of the algorithm, as in this image

[image]

Here the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[italiano,linesnumbered,lined,boxruled,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\def\AlCapFnt{\Large}
\def\AlCapNameFnt{\Large}
\SetAlFnt{\Large}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Somma unaria}\label{alg:Somma unaria}
\SetAlgoLined
\SetKwProg{Fn}{Funzione}{}{}
\Fn{int piu(int $n$, int $m$)}{return $m+n$.}
\SetKwProg{Def}{def}{:}{}
\SetKwFor{While}{while}{:}{}
\Def{piu($m,n$)}{\While{$n!=0$}{$m,n=m+1,n-1$} \textbf{return} $m$.}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Furthermore, there exist a way to set for each algorithm the following options?

```
\def\AlCapFnt{\Large}
\def\AlCapNameFnt{\Large}
\SetAlFnt{\Large}
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Don't pile up questions (and don't make algorithms to use `\Large`). Those options are, anyway, to be set in the preamble and apply to all algorithms.

Comment: You can put your algorithm in a varwidth envrionment and then draw an fbox around it. Here are more details: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/505955/194522

Answer (score 0):

You can set `\AlFnt` directly. In order to display the effect more clearly, I use color instead of font size to show the difference.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italiano,linesnumbered,lined,boxruled,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\SetAlCapNameFnt{\color{green}}
\SetAlCapFnt{\color{red}}
\color{yellow}
\caption{Somma unaria}
\SetAlgoLined
\SetKwProg{Fn}{Funzione}{}{}
\Fn{int piu(int $n$, int $m$)}{return $m+n$.}
\SetKwProg{Def}{def}{:}{}
\SetKwFor{While}{while}{:}{}
\Def{piu($m,n$)}{\While{$n!=0$}{$m,n=m+1,n-1$} \textbf{return} $m$.}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Somma unaria}
\SetAlgoLined
\SetKwProg{Fn}{Funzione}{}{}
\Fn{int piu(int $n$, int $m$)}{return $m+n$.}
\SetKwProg{Def}{def}{:}{}
\SetKwFor{While}{while}{:}{}
\Def{piu($m,n$)}{\While{$n!=0$}{$m,n=m+1,n-1$} \textbf{return} $m$.}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Chiara, but how could I restrict the box adapting it at the algorithm-lenght? Thx

Comment: @Puck Can you be specific? I didn't understand what you meant.